# Flutter: get a list of maps when using Firebase snapshots

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This is my stream function:

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot> getPortfolios() {
    return db
        .collection('users')
        .doc(authService.getUser().uid)
        .collection('portfolios')
        .snapshots();
  }
```

In the `StreamBuilder` I get the list like this:

```
portfolios = snapshot.data!.docs;
```

That gives my a list but a list of `JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot`. With each item I can do `.data()` and I get the info I need, but how could I get this map directly in the list without calling extra methods?

I tried this old answer but it doesn't work anymore:

```
final QuerySnapshot<Object?>? ds = snapshot.data;
final Map<String, dynamic> map = ds!.data; // this .data is not recognised
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ".docs" on the snapshot to get a list of QueryDocumentSnapshot which have some of the same properties as a map, so you can directly reference a value like im doing below:

```
List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> data = snapshot.data!.docs;    
String name = data[i]['name']
```

Here is a full example :

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: db.collection('users').snapshots(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> data = snapshot.data!.docs;

              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data!.size,
                itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                  return Text('${data[i]['name']}');
                },
              );
            } else {
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            }
          },
        ),
```

Alternatively you can map the Stream to any object like this:

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> snaphot = db
        .collection('users')
        .doc(authService.getUser().uid)
        .collection('portfolios')
        .snapshots();

//Map to an object (note that you need to create a "fromJson" method for your object.
Stream<List<YourObject>> dataStream = snaphot.map((list) => list.docs.map((doc) => YourObject.fromJson(doc.data())).toList());
```

Now you can use the "dataStream" in your stream builder and directly reference the items in the list with "snapshot.data".

```
// snapshot.data is now the type:
List<YourObject>
```

Comment: but you have to use a .map, I already have that. I meant to get directly the list of maps without converting them one by one

Comment: I think with the old answer you tried, they are doing it on only a single document within the QuerySnapshot, which will work, but since you are trying to get a collection with a list of documents you can't just do ".data". To use" .data" you would have to access a single document. Hence the ".map" function. Hope this helps.

Comment: yeah, I understand that, that's why I was looking for something else, not that the type of maps that this list returns. I remember this was possible in previous versions of this package. I found some answers but none of them seem to work now. The thing is that the .map is not performing really well and I try to avoid loops when possible and since I store a map, I guess it should be possible to receive the map in the same way right?

Comment: I updated the answer with what I hope answers what you are looking for without looping through the data.

Comment: Let me know if the solution works for you :)

Comment: didn't try to get the property directly since I was getting a JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot and not a normal map. That worked thanks